# Autolayout navigationController TabBarController and ToolBar, what would be the best practice?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios8

I am facing an issue while designing a toolbar.
Let me explain :

I have a navigationController that loads a tabBarController at some point.

Just under the navBar I want to add a toolbar which is available on all tabs.

I have done the following implementation :
ToolBarView which inherits from UIView and its delegate which communicates with each view controller of tabs.
Then when the viewController receives an event from the toolbar, it loads the good controller from a **storyboard** and add its view

This is where I have some layout issue.
The loaded view controller is a search bar top:0px left:0px right 0px
and a tableview under this searchBar top:0px to the search bar, left : 0px right : 0px bottom: 0px

However there is a margin above the search bar and between the search bar and the tableview. I don't know where it comes from !!

Do you have any idea ?

I am using swift and iOS 8.

Moreover, I don't really enjoy the fact the I have to repeat and use exactly the same code for each tabs viewcontroller (Toolbar delegate). But as storyboard doesn't allow to put UIView in UITabBarController, I didn't add it programmatically.

How would you do that ?

Thanking you in advance.

[image: viewcontroller loaded after a toolbar click]

[image: ToolBar load results]

Comment: Best practice for iPhone is to have the toolbar at the bottom. "Always appears at the bottom edge of a screen or view on iPhone" from iOS Human Interface Guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Insets`. This will remove the space above you list.

[image]